# real-world dimensions in qgraphicsscene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, cad

I'm writing a small CAD application in Qt 5.1 and I'm trying to figure out how to get the coordinates of the QGraphicsScene to correspond to real-world dimensions. I intend to keep coordinates in their original form of (value, unit) to preserve data when switching from mm to inches, for example.

I've found in their documentation (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/coordsys.html) that the default unit corresponds to 1 pixel on pixel-based paint devices and 1/72 inch for print-based devices.

Is this the conversion I should use (72 units per inch)? That's not particularly convenient... Is there a better way to associate real-world dimensions with the coordinates in a QGraphicsScene? Can this conversion be adjusted?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is the real-world size of the display something the computer can even reliably know?  e.g. what if the image is being displayed on an LCD projector, then the real-world size will depend on how far away the display surface is...

Comment: and LCD projector is a pixel-based device, so it doesn't care. A printer, however, does have a fixed physical size and the computer has to make a conversion from the otherwise unitless coordinates of the qgraphicsscene to a real world value

Comment: How about using whatever is convenient (e.g. 10 ~ 1mm) in the scene and then scale as needed for printing?

Answer (score 0):

Relativity is the important thing here and there's no direct correlation between what you see in a QGraphicsScene and the real-world, unless you decide to create a representative scale.

You can happily create a molecular model to scale, of atoms inside an object, or you could model a solar system that allows you to travel between stars and galaxies. What is important is what you as the developer decide your scale is going to be.

In a solar system, going from a GraphicsScene coordinate position of (0,0) to (10,0) could mean a distance of 10 meters or 10 miles. So long as the objects in the scene are modelled to the same scale and positioned in the scene using that scale, that's what matters.

When it comes to printing, I agree with @FrankOsterfeld that it's a matter of scaling the view on the scene. If you want a direct correlation between what you see on screen and what you print on paper, you'd be better off not using a QGraphicsScene here.

Comment: "If you want a direct correlation between what you see on screen and what you print on paper, you'd be better off not using a QGraphicsScene here."

What would I use in that case?